# Need to know tolerance of certain rubbers to pH 11 Bases

Tags: materials, material-science

I need to know whether neoprene and HNBR (Hydrogenated Nitrile Butadiene Rubber) seals can tolerate pH11 atmosphere. The seals would be in touch with a fertilizer which is pH11.

Comment: Should be in the data sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per https://fluidpowerjournal.com/demystifying/ HNBR is

Recommended for:

- Hot water and steam
- Oils and fuels

Not recommended for:

- Polar solvents
- Strong acids
- Chlorinated hydrocarbons

If I had a choice, I'd try for something more akin to pvc or ptfe...

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Someone said use Kalrez, but some the problem is that readymade off the market parts seldom give specification of material used, unless you buy the expensive stuff.